# jenkins script console - can i use jenkins pipeline DSL in script console

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

i want to try some jenkins pipeline DSL methods. a sample code

```
node("linux-agent") {
  sh "ls -ltra"
}
```

i just want to try few changes to the script very quick. so i try to run this in "jenkins script console ". but seems it does not work in that way. i have to edit the job sonfig every time and run the job to test my code.

1. is there any quick way to test script changes without putting them in a piepline job?
2. is there a way to run this in "jenkins script console"?

thanks in advance !!

Comment: You can experiment with "Replay" feature in the job view, it allows you to edit the pipeline before replaying it.

Answer (score 6):

The Jenkins script console is for Groovy scripts only, pipeline steps are not available there.

However, you can create a new Jenkins "pipeline" job that has a textbox where you can put your pipeline coding and run it. 
It works well if you have one window open to trigger the job and another one to edit & apply the changes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In script console you can do the following:

- Create a temp project
- Run a build for the project
- Print the log
- Delete the project afterwards

---

```
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.job.WorkflowJob;
import org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowDefinition;
  
def jobName = 'tmp-project'

script = '''
node("linux-agent") {
  sh "ls -ltra"
}
'''
// Create Project
p = Jenkins.instance.createProject(WorkflowJob, jobName)
p.setDefinition(new CpsFlowDefinition(script, false));
p.save()

// Schedule Build
Jenkins.instance.queue.schedule(p, 0, null, null)

// Wait until build starts
while( p.builds.size() < 1 ) { }

// Wait until build finishes
def execution = p.builds[0].getExecutionPromise().get()
while (! execution.isComplete() ){}

// Print log and delete project
println p.builds[0].log
p.delete()
```

Answer (score 0):

The Pipeline (workflow) engine runs Groovy in an extended Groovy interpreter, sets up its own classloader, injects its own bindings, and IIRC sets up a custom metaclass. The modified interpreter uses "continuation passing style" (CPS) to permit program state to be serialized and passed around between nodes.

I don't think it's possible to switch a running `GroovyScriptEngine` to run with the [Groovy CPS](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps) interpreter. And the pipeline/workflow stuff is written around CPS, so it won't run in a regular Groovy script engine.

So in short, the answer is no. The workaround @Christopher posted is probably the best option until or unless somebody can be bothered implementing a Jenkins plugin that extends the script console to run groovy-cps with the pipeline metaclass, classloader, etc.

### Details

The Groovy Pipeline DSL runtime is implemented by the [workflow-cps-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-cps/) on top of the [groovy plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/groovy/) and [Groovy CPS](https://github.com/cloudbees/groovy-cps). The  and the core steps are provided by the [workflow-basic-steps-plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/workflow-basic-steps/).

The critical classes appear to be

- [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsFlowExecution`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecution.java)
- [`org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/DSL.java)

It's all a bit thin on comments in most places, but there's useful detail in [CpsFlowExecution.java](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecution.java#L157).

You can't instantiate a `DSL` (the `steps` variable that provides the guts of the pipeline) without a `FlowExecutionOwner`, which requires a `CpsFlowExecution`, which in turn needs a CPS interpreter. [`CpsFlowExecution`](https://github.com/jenkinsci/workflow-cps-plugin/blob/master/src/main/java/org/jenkinsci/plugins/workflow/cps/CpsFlowExecution.java) is very heavily tied into everything. The code also expects that `this` (your script) will be an instance of `CpsScript`, wheras the script console is just a plain Groovy `Script` instance.

It looks to me like you'd need a plugin that took over the Script Console to instantiate a CPS-enabled interpreter and fake a FlowExecution. Too hard for me at the moment.